# MSR Daily Activity 3D dataset matlab source code

Tags: matlab, action

I am searching for any matlab code that reads the skeleton text files from the dataset (MSR Daily Activity 3D). I can't figure how to understand how the files are written and what they represent ? Also, don't know how to parse them to extract the features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the matlab code which read the depth sequences.
in each loop of 'for ei = 1:2',it read all the depth data to depth(a 3D matrix) from a bin file.

```
clear;close all;clc;
binPath = 'MSR Daily Activity 3D dataset\Depth';
for ai = 1:16
    for si = 1:10
        for ei = 1:2
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%
            [acsr,susr,exsr]=getsr(ai,si,ei);
            %%%%%% getsr(ai,si,ei) convert ai,si,ei to double bits
            %%%%%% for example, if ai=3, acsr is 03
            %%%%%%%%%%%

            binfile = [binPath,'\a',acsr,'_s',susr,'_e',exsr,'_depth.bin'];        
            if ~exist(binfile,'file');
                disp('error');
                continue;
            end;
            disp(binfile);

            fileread = fopen(binfile);      
            if fileread<0
               disp('no such file.');
               return;
            end

            header = fread(fileread,3,'uint=>uint');
            nnof = header(1); ncols = header(2); nrows = header(3);

            depths = zeros(ncols, nrows, nnof);
            for f = 1:nnof
                frame = zeros( ncols, nrows);
                for row = 1:nrows
                    tempRow = fread(fileread, ncols, 'uint=>uint');
                    tempRowID = fread(fileread, ncols, 'uint8');%%%%%
                    frame(:,row) = tempRow;
                end
                depth(:,:,f) = frame;
                clear tempRow tempRowID;
            end

            fclose(fileread);
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The site http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zliu/ActionRecoRsrc/ tells you exactly how they're organised. They also provide some C++ example loaders.

"The format of the skeleton file is as follows. The first integer is the number of frames. The second integer is the number of joints which is always 20. For each frame, the first integer is the number of rows. This integer is 40 when there is exactly one skeleton being detected in this frame. It is zero when no skeleton is detected. It is 80 when two skeletons are detected (in that case which is rare, we simply use the first skeleton in our experiments). For most of the frames, the number of rows is 40. Each joint corresponds to two rows. The first row is its real world coordinates (x,y,z) and the second row is its screen coordinates plus depth (u, v, depth) where u and v are normalized to be within [0,1]. For each row, the integer at the end is supposed to be the confidence value, but it is not useful."

Hope this helps.